# Move an object along a straight path on an angle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, trigonometry

I have an object at $x,y$ and I want it to move along a straight line on an angle of roughly $65^\circ$ and I know what the different of $X$ is but I do not know what the $Y$ should be.

So for example I am doing $a^2+b^2=c^2$, but I don't know $b^2$ or $c^2$, but I know an angle and I don't remember how to get the $b^2$ or $c^2$ from an angle.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if i understand your question, but...

if you're at the origin and go to a point $(x,y)$ at an angle of 65 degrees from the positive $x$-axis *and* you know $x$, then $y=x\tan(65^{\circ})$

Comment: That's what I was looking for TAN!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the slope of your line. Call it $m$,

$\tan \theta=m$, your line is $mx+c=y$.

Rotating the angle by $65^0$, which gives either $\theta-65$ or $\theta+65$.

Now find the slope of the line and eventually the equation of that line!